# Is there a way to affiliate a script with a certain organization?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, http-status-code-401

I want to use a script to automate the completion of a google form, but this form can only be filled out by members of my organization: when the script runs, it brings up an 401 error.

If I run the script on a test form, it works just fine until I restrict that form to members of my organization. Is there a way to give the script permission to work in my organization?

Comment: Try `ScriptApp.getOauthToken()`?

Comment: Deploy this as internal add-on and you must be restricting to internal users.